# help running simple Ext JS example?

Tags: extjs

I downloaded Ext JS 4.0.2a and I'm trying to do the Ext JS tutorial.  I go the "essentials" example working, so I'm pretty sure I'm set up right.  I'm trying to do the grid example here ...

http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Tutorial:Getting_Productive

... but I can't get the grid to display.

My ExtStart.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Introduction to Ext 2.0: Starter Page</title>

    <!-- Include Ext and app-specific scripts: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ExtStart.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Ext stylesheets here: -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ExtStart.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="grid-example"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my ExtStart.js is exactly like on the tutorial site like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    // sample static data for the store
    var myData = [['Apple',29.89,0.24,0.81,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Ext',83.81,0.28,0.34,'9/12 12:00am'],
        ['Google',71.72,0.02,0.03,'10/1 12:00am'],
        ['Microsoft',52.55,0.01,0.02,'7/4 12:00am'],
        ['Yahoo!',29.01,0.42,1.47,'5/22 12:00am']
    ];

    // create the data store
    var ds = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        fields: [
           {name: 'company'},
           {name: 'price', type: 'float'},
           {name: 'change', type: 'float'},
           {name: 'pctChange', type: 'float'},
           {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'}
        ]
    });

    // manually load local data
    ds.loadData(myData);

    // create the colum Manager
    var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
            {header: 'Company', width: 160, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'company'},
            {header: 'Price', width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'price'},
            {header: 'Change', width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'change'},
            {header: '% Change', width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'pctChange'},
            {header: 'Last Updated', width: 85, sortable: true,
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'}
    ]);


    // create the Grid
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: ds,
        colModel: colModel,
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        title: 'My First Grid'
    });

    // render the grid to the specified div in the page
    grid.render('grid-example');
});
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?  Sadly stumped. :(

rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using ExtJS4 but are referring to a legacy documentation.

There have been quite a few changes to the components and how they need to be wired together between the version that document was written for and version 4 that you are using.

Here is the array grid (and other) example(s) for ExtJS 4. -

[HTML](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/array-grid.html)
[Javascript code](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/extjs/examples/grid/array-grid.js)

For example, you are using `Ext.grid.GridPanel`. This is no longer valid. (Use `Ext.grid.Panel` instead)

Comment: Yeah, <title>Introduction to Ext 2.0: Starter Page</title> is sort of a dead giveaway ;)

Comment: Thanks.  I saw the version numbers, but I just assumed that since these tutorials that are directly linked off Sencha's main page that they would still be valid.  Why don't they update them?  How frustrating.  Thanks for the help!